# Image_url helper won't find an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an image at `app/assets/images/my_image.jpg`. In a view this `image_url "my_image.jpg"` results in the 404 error. What can be a cause?

Answer (score 0):

Try using image_tag instead of image_url

```
  image_tag("my_image.jpg")
```

this returns an HTML image tag for the source. It could be a full path or a file name.